# WebRequest with Bearer Authorization in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webrequest, bearer-token

I would need to send a POST request to a remote server, which requires a Bearer Authorization.
this is my VB.NET code:

```
Public Shared Function syncAsana() As String
    Dim result As String
    Try
        Dim token As String = "TOKEN"
        Dim uri As String = "https://URL/api/1.0/tasks"
        Dim postData As String = "assignee=email&notes=TEST_NOTES&name=NOME 1&projects=123985"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.PreAuthenticate = True
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using dataStream1 As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            ................
            result = responseFromServer
        End Using
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

the problem is that **I always get the error The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive**
the same request made with jquery / ajax or with curl works.
I have tried both from the local server launched by visual studio, and by putting the code on the production server.
could you tell me where i'm wrong?